# Process RxJava observables in dynamic order

Tags: android, rx-java

In my UI I have two buttons. Each triggers a network call. If the user clicks button A, then clicks button B, the networks calls must be completed in that order. If call A fails, call B should not occur.

Is there an easy way to do this in RxJava? I've looked into different operators (e.g. concat, merge, zip) but none seem to do quite what I am looking for. Links and articles appreciated. I know this is possible without using RxJava by saving state information but I am looking to avoid that

Comment: What happens if B is clicked first? Is that allowed? What if only A is clicked? If the user clicked A and B, is the user able to click any of the buttons again?

Comment: is there a timing difference between clicking A and B? Is the scenario different if B is clicked before A's network call finishes?

Comment: I guess you should check your design maybe. Like disable the button B before request A completed.